# How to correctly remove mountnfs from /etc/init.d/

Tags: debian, nfs, init-script, init.d

Cleaning up the boot process of a Debian squeeze installation running on kernel 3.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64, I spotted several mountnfs scripts in /etc/init.d/:

```
# ls /etc/init.d/ | grep mountnfs
mountnfs-bootclean.sh
mountnfs.sh
umountnfs.sh
```

Removing fails, with commands like:

```
# update-rc.d -f mountnfs remove
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

For "*mountnfs*", I have also tried: umountnfs, mountnfs-bootclean, nfs, nfs-common.

**Update #1**
Also tried without success: umountnfs.sh, mountnfs.sh.

The result is that the mountnfs-bootclean, mountnfs and unmountnfs.sh are still in /etc/init.d/ and their corresponding run level folders.

Just removing those files using `rm` doesn't seem the right way. I though that these init.d files belong to installed packages. However I can't really find any installed NFS package:

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep nfs
libnfsidmap2                    install
```

How do I correctly remove all mountNFS scripts from init.d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check which package a file belongs to, use `dpkg -S`:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/init.d/mountnfs.sh
initscripts: /etc/init.d/mountnfs.sh
```

mountnfs.sh belongs to an **essential** package called initscripts.

Unless you wrote them, you should never remove scripts from /etc/init.d/. That is why the utility update-rc.d exists: to remove their symlinks from the **/etc/rc*.d/** directories in an easier way.

update-rc.d requires you to call scripts by their names and, because of their dependencies, disabling them in this order should work:

```
update-rc.d mountnfs-bootclean.sh remove ### mountnfs-bootclean.sh first
update-rc.d mountnfs.sh remove
update-rc.d umountnfs.sh remove
```

However, I tried that last month, and it will leave you with a broken system (unable to start X, if I can remember well). The thing is that `mountnfs-bootclean.sh` does some needed system cleanup, although its name doesn't imply, and it depends on `mountnfs.sh`. So you can't disable either.

You may consider that as a bug in Debian init scripts: you are forced to have the init script without having any network filesystems. It's annoying, I know.

If you insist in removing them, and need to revert the changes, you'll have to re-enable them in reverse order, because `mountnfs-bootclean.sh` needs `mountnfs.sh` to be enabled first:

```
update-rc.d umountnfs.sh defaults
update-rc.d mountnfs.sh defaults
update-rc.d mountnfs-bootclean.sh defaults ### mountnfs-bootclean.sh last
```

Comment: Thanks for the warning about mountnfs-bootclean. The result of `root@debian:~# update-rc.d mountnfs.sh remove
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: Service mountnfs has to be enabled to start service mountnfs-bootclean
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
root@debian:~# update-rc.d umountnfs.sh remove
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing` is that mountnfs.sh and umountnfs.sh are still in /etc/init.d.

Comment: Adding the force parameter to `update-rc.d` didn't improve. `Mountnfs.sh` and `umountnfs.sh` are still in `/etc/init.d/`.

Comment: You have to run on that exact order. Also, they will and should remain on /etc/init.d. They'll be unlinked from /etc/rcS.d. It is unwise to remove anything from /etc/init.d.

Comment: I updated my answer with more explanations.